# PDO::Query to array

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I got a basic simple query to get data from a table. It doesn't need any parameters so I want to use a basic `PDO::Query` way.

I got this:

```
$items = $cmsDbh->query("SELECT * FROM `tbl1`");
```

Now this is my AJAX file, I want to return the data as a JSON object. I tried using:

```
echo json_encode($items);
```

But then I get a JSON object which contains the `queryString` (the SELECT * FROM `tbl1`).

I don't want to use `PDO::Prepare`, is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Don't you need to fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo json_encode($items->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Yeah I already figured that out, was stupid and didn't read the documentation well enough on PHP.net. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Was stupid. Appearantly `PDO::Query` returns a `PDOStatement` object, so you can just use `fetchAll`. Working code:

```
echo json_encode($items->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```